# SonarQube Plugin for Bamboo

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

I have Bamboo version 5.2 configured on my local system.

I want to install a sonarqube plugin in my bamboo instance. I found a plugin for version 5.1, but was unable to find a plugin for version 5.2.

From where do I get the appropriate plugin and how to configure the sonar runner task with it?

Answer (score 0):

it is not supported for your version of Bamboo. Its a open source plugin so you can pick it up, work on it and make it compatible with your Bamboo verison